# Why Kafka REST Proxy API not Consuming data in JSON Format?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-hub

I'm try to access message hub instance by using kafka rest API. when i'm sending post request through Postman Client and giving `Content-Type` as `application/vnd.kafka.json.v1+json` it's giving me the following response

```
{
  "error_code": 415,
  "message": "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

could anyone please help me with that?.
I'm also passing api key in `X-Auth-Token` Header.

Answer (score 5):

the accepted content-types when producing messages are

```
"application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1+json"
"application/vnd.kafka.v1+json"
"application/vnd.kafka+json"
"application/json"
```

but in all cases, the Message Hub REST service expects the content to be formatted as

```
"application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1+json"
```

i.e. the value of "value" to be base64-encoded.
E.g. something like

```
{"records":[{"value":"YmxhaGJsYWg="}]}
```